# Button doesn't redirect to activity but crashes app instead

Tags: android, xml, button, android-activity

My button doesnt open up a new activity, the app crashes instead. I've even copied the source code from **http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-button-click-new-activity-example/** and try running it on my own but still the app crashes. I cant seem to find the problem.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from activity_main.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Locate the button in activity_main.xml
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.MyButton);

    // Capture button clicks
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // Start NewActivity.class
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    secondActivity.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
}

}
```

**XML BUTTON**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/MyButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Comment: Have you added your secondActivity in Manifest ? if yes, Can you share logcat

Comment: Please post a crash log here what is the error display?

Comment: OMG, i didnt realise i havent include the 2ndactivity inside the Manifest.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**YOUR CODE IS FINE!**

The most likely cause of this behavior is that `secondActivity` is not registered in your manifest. Check whether it is and try again. If it's not, you can simply register it by adding the line below inside the `application` tag of your `manifest.xml` file.

```
<activity android:name=".secondActivity" />
```

Re-run your code and try again. It'd most likely work this time.

I hope this helps.. Merry coding!

Answer (score 0):

Place this code snippet:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button button;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from activity_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Locate the button in activity_main.xml
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.MyButton);

        // Capture button clicks
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                // Start NewActivity.class
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        secondActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Register secondActivity in manifest.xml

```
<activity
            android:name=".secondActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

This may help you

Answer (score 0):

As per the tutorial link you provided, second activity's name is NewActivity.class. In your code, it looks like you modified it to secondActivity.class.

So ensure to have it manifest also

```
 <activity android:name=".secondActivity" >
        </activity>
```

And always use PascalCase for Classes and camelCase for methods